# How to set a custom color for html angle brackets in VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

Under

> Tools => Options => Environment => Fonts and Colors

there is `Text Editor` settings. Under `Display Items` there are items with names starting with `HTML` keyword. But I cannot find there a name for `HTML` angle brackets. How are they called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, angle brackets (`<` and `>`) are in the `XML Delimiter` category.

This will apply to

> XML Syntax delimiters, including `<`, `<?`, `<!`, `<!--`, `-->`, `?>`, `<![`, `]]>`,
>   `>` and `[`, `]`

Note that this will not change the C# files angle brackets.

More info: [Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012, "HTML Tag Delimiter" is what worked for me. "HTML Element Name" is the tag itself.

Comment: This is also true in Visual Studio 2015.